# makepkg Is claiming missing depencies but they already installed

Tags: linux, git, fedora, kde

Hey normally I post a question about a script that I made, but I am trying out something different this time. Recently I read a report that the developer of KDE has decided to revive the original KDE1 so it can be installed on modern systems and I was so excited. Being a KDE enthusiast and a lover of the old looks, I jumped at the opportunity to build and install it for myself. The only packages that I could find however were git packages of the required packages in order to do the install. I had never used git before, so I figured why not learn something new, so I downloaded the git packages only to find out that they only contained one file each. Each of theses files are named PKGBUILD, and thus started the rather lengthy process of learning how to build a package from those files. To make a long story short, I figured out how (I run Fedora 24 not Arch Linux) but when I went to do the actual build, i encountered a rather annoying and unavoidable roadblock. I have tried to post the results of qt1 build on fpaste, but it was too large, so request any further details, and I will add them in my reply. I am rather puzzled as to why this happened, and how to fix it. I want to call on you all for any ideas or help. I will provide as much extra information upon request as I can. Thank you for your help and understanding in advance.

Comment: Can you please add which missing dependencies makepkg complains about, which PKGBUILD you are using and which (versions of) those dependencies are installed?

Comment: sure the it says this:

`[dcarr@localhost qt1]$ makepkg
==> Making package: qt1 1.45-1 (Mon Oct 17 00:02:09 EDT 2016)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Missing dependencies:
  -> libx11
  -> libxext
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> ERROR: Could not resolve all dependencies.`

Comment: Okay; which PKGBUILD are you using? Presumably it can be found online? Which versions of libx11 and libxext do you have installed?

Comment: sry i have not been on for a while. i got the qt1 git from this stie: [https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/qt1/](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/qt1/). As for the dependency versions, the best answer i can give is this: `Packages (14) filesystem-2015.09-1  glibc-2.24-2  iana-etc-20160927-1  kbproto-1.0.7-1  libxau-1.0.8-2  libxcb-1.12-1  libxdmcp-1.1.2-1  linux-api-headers-4.7-1  tzdata-2016g-1  xcb-proto-1.12-2
              xextproto-7.3.0-1  xproto-7.0.31-1  libx11-1.6.4-1  libxext-1.3.3-1`
i hope this provides the answer you are looking for.

Comment: i used this site: [https://github.com/FZUG/repo/wiki/use-yaour](https://github.com/FZUG/repo/wiki/use-yaour) for directions on how to do this. I looked closer at your question and my current installed version of libx11 and libxext is 1.6.3-3.x86_64.fc24 and 1.3.3-3.x86_64.fc24 respectively. the packages on the above comment is what pacman trys to install.

Comment: The used manual is on  https://github.com/FZUG/repo/wiki/use-yaourt (note the trailing t)

Comment: Note that the manual specifically disables all dependency checking. The pacman/yaourt/makepkg system will register only dependencies installed with pacman. You presumably installed libxext and libx11 with yum. If you want to compile with makepkg instead of yaourt (different from what your manual does), comment out the depends definition (line 10) in the PKGBUILD.

Comment: hmm i didnt think of that thx i will give it a try